# Is there some convenient way to convert rmarkdown to pandoc markdown?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I use `rstudio` to write `r-markdown`, but sometimes it is not compatible with `markdown` support by `pandoc`(math for example. If there is a way allow me to convert `r-markdown` to `pandoc` markdown, then it will be convenient to export my articles to `pdf`, `org`, `rts`, `latex`...

https://pandoc.org/ also seems doesn't mention `rmarkdown` support.

I have tried to export `.html` form rstudio and use pandoc convert the html file back to markdown, but it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `pandoc` is used to create pdf and other formats from r-markdown. Therefore there is an intermediate file with `pandoc` compatible markdown. You could retain this file by:

```
rmarkdown::render("document.Rmd", output_format = "pdf_document", run_pandoc = FALSE)
```